# Bearer token is not validating with authorize attribute

Tags: api, asp.net-web-api, owin, bearer-token

I have a simple api controller with a method "GetDashboard" that contains an Authorize attribute like so...

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Dashboard")]
public class DashboardController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    [Route("GetDashboard")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetDashboard()
    {
       //Do stuff...
    }
}
```

I'm using Owin pipeline and bearer tokens for my api authorization and in my Owin configuration i have created two authorization providers using the app.Map() functionality to select the correct mechanism for authorizing users  depending your on your entry point to the api like so...

```
        app.Map("/RouteOne", app1 =>
        {
            appAteb.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            appAteb.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            PublicClientId = "app1";
            OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Authenticate1"),
                Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
                AllowInsecureHttp = false
            };

            app1.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);

        });


        app.Map("/RouteTwo", app2 =>
        {
            app2.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            app2.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            PublicClientId = "app2";
            OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Authenticate2"),
                Provider = new AnotherAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
                AllowInsecureHttp = false

            };
            app2.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
        });
```

Both mechanisms authenticate correctly, the bearer token is generated and passed back to the browser however when then use the token for authorization on my dashboard controller it returns a 401 Unorthorized?

I suspect its something to do with the app.map because if i remove it and just have one mechanism calls to my dashboard controller work fine however i need to be able to use both mechanisms of authorization and my api controllers to accept the tokens.

Any help on solving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `RoutePrefix` of your action `GetDashboard()` should include the route of one of the maps. For example you could redefine your maps as `api/RouteOne` and `api/RouteTwo` and then the route prefix could be for example `[RoutePrefix("api/RouteOne/Dashboard")]`.
I hope it helps.